# reduce number of rows by joining rows based on id and category

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

The data I have is below format :

[image]

Data I want in the final table:

[image]

Not sure how to do this one.

Comment: How did you generate the data?  I'm guessing you used a query and that query could be fixed.

Comment: As a rule the [`mysql`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info) and [`tsql`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) tags are mutually exclusive. Do you need a solution that works for both? Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Your actual date of 10-jan does not exist in your sample data, have you checked your question thoroughly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by to achieve that.

```
select id, category, max(actual_date) actual_date, max(planned_date)planned_date
from tablename
group by  id, category
```